# limit characters using strlen

Tags: php, joomla, substr, if-statement

I am trying to limit the number of characters that appear in a title.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here (I'm a novice!), but the title appears full length and the '...' does not appear.

Any help much appreciated!

```
<? if ($params->get('itemid')) $itemid = '&Itemid='.$params->get('itemid'); else $itemid = ''; ?>
<? $title = $event->title ?>
<? $title = substr($title, 0, 20); ?>
<? if (strlen($title) == 20) $title .= '...' ; ?>
<? if (KRequest::get('get.view', 'string') == 'events' || isset($module)) : ?>
    <h1 class="title" itemprop="name">
        <a href="<?=@route('option=joomla_component&view=event&id='.$event->id.$itemid)?>" itemprop="url"><?=$event->title?></a>
    </h1>
<? endif ?>
```

Comment: what's the problem? why new users never write what's the problem

Comment: You don't have to wrap *every line* in `<? ... ?>` tags. It just makes the code completely unreadable.

Comment: what error are you getting? the code you have edited seems to be correct

Comment: @Juhana: It allows to skip `;` in the end of every line. For newbies who don't understand what it does it helps a lot ;-)))

Comment: The title is not appearing shortened to 20 characters and the '...' is not appearing either.

Comment: do clear your cache from the joomla backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using $title and not $event->title in your output?

Comment: In other words, you're simply using the wrong variable in the line that reads ... itemprop="url"><?=$event->title ...

Comment: This answer sticks closer to the original code while still being correct, the current accepted answer changes something which isn't wrong.

Answer (score 1):

See the 2 comments.  It should make it work.

```
    <? 
    if ( $params->get('itemid') ) {
        $itemid = '&Itemid='. $params->get('itemid'); 
    else 
        $itemid = ''; 
    $title = $event->title; 
    if ( strlen( $title ) > 20 ) $title = substr( $title, 0, 17).'...';  // Need to add a substr
    if ( KRequest::get('get.view', 'string') == 'events' || isset( $module ) ) : ?>     
        <h1 class="title" itemprop="name">
            <a href="<?=@route('option=joomla_component&view=event&id='.$event->id.$itemid)?>" 
                itemprop="url">
                <?= $title; // note the change here ?>
            </a>
       </h1> 
    <? endif ?>
```

Comment: I don't see why this is an accepted answer? If you look through the code the ... will never be added but all the titles will be truncated to 20 characters. The line `$title = substr ( $title, 0, 20 );` should be removed or the `if ( strlen( $title ) > 20 )` will never be true.

Comment: I did not see originally that the substr was there.  I added it and totally missed that she had it on the line above.  I fixed it.

Comment: You should probably change the `substr( $title, 0, 17)` to `substr( $title, 0, 20)` too.

Comment: It was taking into account the 3 characters that are added with the "..."

Comment: Yeah but the original poster was not, so that may have been intentional ; )

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will answer your question, but maybe you should try this code:

```
<?php
if ( $params->get( 'itemid' ) ) {
    $itemid = '&Itemid='.$params->get('itemid');
} else {
    $itemid = '';
}
$title = $event->title;
if ( strlen( $title ) >= 20 ) {
    $title = substr( $title, 0, 20 );
    $title .= '...';
}
if ( KRequest::get( 'get.view', 'string' ) == 'events' || isset( $module ) ) :
?>
<h1 class="title" itemprop="name">
    <a href="<?= @route( 'option=joomla_component&view=event&id=' . $event->id . $itemid ) ?>" itemprop="url"><?= $title ?></a>
</h1>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

The main problem is that you're transforming the $title variable and display the $event->title variable. Besides, you're looking for strings of an EXACT length of 20 to add the "...", but you should add it to any string with 20 or more characters.

I hope it helped!